# Spree 3.x -Create a custom promotion rule

Tags: spree

I wanted to create a custom promotion rule to check if User buys an item again, they will be discount 10% of item’s price. (Admin able to config this in Spree's CMS)
Ideally, in user order page user would see the “Buy again” button, the item will be add to cart and the cart will be discount 10%.

Anyone can tell me how to do it, there is any extension/code that I can reference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your needed rules but you can define custom promotional rules. Go through with the following document:

```
https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/promotions.html
```

Comment: Correct URL (2019) is:  https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/promotions.html